# Close offcanvas with a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to close the offcanvas with the close button inside the offcanvas. Right now, I can only close it with the button I opened it with. What did I do wrong? See attached code.

```js
(function mainScript() {
  "use strict";

  const offcanvasToggle = document.querySelector('[data-bs-toggle="offcanvas"], [data-bs-dissmiss="offcanvas"]');
  const offcanvasCollapse = document.querySelector(".offcanvas-collapse");

  offcanvasToggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
    offcanvasCollapse.classList.toggle("open");
  });
})();
```

```css
.offcanvas-collapse {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  /* Height of navbar */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #343a40;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out, visibility 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.offcanvas-collapse.open {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
    <div id="navbar" class="flex-wrap center">
      <div id="nav-toggler-wrapper">
        <button id="nav-toggler" aria-label="Menü" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="menu-label">Menu</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    

  <div id="sidenav" class="offcanvas offcanvas-collapse">
    <div class="offcanvas-header flex-wrap center between">
      <button id="nav-toggler" data-bs-dissmiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="menu-label">Close</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`, because you try to select more then one element and use `forEach` for apply `eventListner` to each one like:

```js
(function mainScript() {
  "use strict";

  const offcanvasToggle = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="offcanvas"], [data-bs-dissmiss="offcanvas"]');
  const offcanvasCollapse = document.querySelector(".offcanvas-collapse");

  offcanvasToggle.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", function() {
      offcanvasCollapse.classList.toggle("open");
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
.offcanvas-collapse {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  /* Height of navbar */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #343a40;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out, visibility 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.offcanvas-collapse.open {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="flex-wrap center">
  <div id="nav-toggler-wrapper">
    <button id="nav-toggler" aria-label="Menü" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="menu-label">Menu</span>
        </button>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="sidenav" class="offcanvas offcanvas-collapse">
  <div class="offcanvas-header flex-wrap center between">
    <button id="nav-toggler" data-bs-dissmiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="menu-label">Close</span>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```